# How can I modify a trigger so that it emails upon edit, but not so quickly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a script that creates additional files upon submission of a Google Form.  It also sets up a trigger for said new document, so that people are emailed when any edits are made to the document after its creation, e.g.

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmailOnModification")
         .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId))
         .onEdit()
         .create();
```

The logic all works, but...  the trigger is extremely sensitive.  *Every* time someone makes a single keystroke in the document, it fires.  It doesn't make a lot of sense to repeatedly fire as someone writes a paragraph; it makes more sense to, say, fire 10 minutes after the last edit.  (Or something.  Anything that doesn't spam emails.)

Is there a way to modify the trigger so that it fires less often (I do **not** want a time-based trigger), or otherwise programmatically change how frequently Google Sheets saves?

As a last resort, I suppose I could create a hidden sheet that captures last modified time and a condition not to send an email if subsequent modifications are less than X minutes ago, but that's kind of clunky and not really appealing.  Hoping I can do it entirely in Google Scripts instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/) to save a timestamp of the last time that the email was sent and compare it to the actual time of the current execution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you could implement this to suit your needs,but since you don't want a time based trigger, and you are already using `onEdit()`, you should be able to use 
`onEdit(e)` and `e.oldValue` to check if the change is worth the message.